# Generics inheritance and Swift compiler

Tags: swift, generics

Here's an interesting challenge...

For some job reasons I'm trying to automatise the management of all `UITableView` objects we code in the office. The thing is that when you have an application with lots of `UITableView` objects, you'll constantly repeat the same data-sourcing pattern: `numberOfRowInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and so on...

I've been thinking about this, and I've found a way to automatise all this repeating data-sourcing pattern: generics inheritance.

Code is too long to post here, so I've created a [GitHub repo here](https://github.com/think-dev/GenericTableViewController/).

You'll find a Playground demonstrating how the concept works, under the Concept folder.

Under the Framework folder you'll find a non-working approach to transform the Playground concept to a Swift Framework. By now it seems to be a Swift compiler bug that makes it not work. Here's what the command line compiler throws while trying to compile the Framework:

```
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
2017-01-12 07:37:36.228 xcodebuild[64275:5358071]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-11766.1/IDEFoundation/Playgrounds/IDEPlaygroundAuxiliarySourceCompilerOperation.m:386
Details:  Unable to read diagnostics from file ".../GenericTableViewController/build/GenericTableViewController.build/Debug-iphoneos/GenericTableViewController.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GenericTableViewController.dia" (Invalid File): Invalid diagnostics signature
Function: void XCGenerateDiagnosticsFromFile(NSString *__strong, NSString *__strong, NSDictionary *__strong, NSDictionary *__strong, IDEActivityLogSectionRecorder *__strong, BOOL (^__strong)(IDEActivityLogMessage *__strong))
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ffb7c2a3f60>{number = 14, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

It's pretty strange because the same code works under a Playground but does not compile under a standard Xcode project...

Can anyone contribute?

Comment: Please pick a title that better describes your issue.

Comment: The message is pretty clear about this being a (potential) bug so I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Already solved, check next answer

Comment: I suggest you taking a look at RxSwift. And specifically http://yannickloriot.com/2016/01/make-uitableview-reactive-with-rxswift/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a bit of investigation I've ended up compiling it correctly. I've found that the `Optimization Level` on `Build Settings` is the key.

By default it's setted on `Noone` for Debug and `Fast, Whole Module Optimization` for Release. Now if you set Debug to `Fast, Whole Module Optimization` it compiles on Debug and you can use the above piece of code.

I'll update the GitHub repo for sharing. Thank you all.

More info: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2565